# Unity to Android - apk installs but doesn't run

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

So I followed this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MtiUx_szKbI

I can install the apk on my android phone (Huawei) but when I open the app it shows:

[image]

Can you please help me?

Comment: What's the specific problem and what do you expect?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The best way to get help on this site is to do the work up front to make it easy for other users to provide feedback. Have a look at this help article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This article on [how to create a minimal, verifiable, and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be useful as well. Show your work, include code examples and error messages, and consider what your question will look like from the outside to someone who has no idea how your code works.

Comment: Its an AR app that need to track an image to show something. When I open it, it only shows this, it is supposed to open the camera to start tracking

Comment: Could it be that you have the wrong scene set as the intitiation scene of your project? If so try and move the scene you wish to be initiated upon start in the top of all the scenes displayed in build settings.